# index is not visible to DBIx::Class

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I have this small perl code which is going to add a record to a table but I am confused why DBIC is not able to see the primary key?

I am not able to find any answer anywhere. First the names of table and columns were camelCase, which I then changed to underscore but it just won't run :(

```
$ ./test.pl
DBIx::Class::ResultSource::unique_constraint_columns(): Unknown unique constraint node_id on 'node' at ./test.pl line 80
```

code:

```
sub addNode
{
    my $node = shift; my $lcNode = lc($node);
    my $id = $schema
        ->resultset('Node')
        ->find_or_create
        (
            { node_name => $lcNode },
            { key => 'node_id' }
        );
    return $id;
}
```

table details:

```
mysql> desc node;
+------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| node_id    | mediumint(5) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| node_name  | varchar(50)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| node_notes | varchar(1000)         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

DBIx::Class::Resultset:

```
$ cat Node.pm
use utf8;
package Testdb::Schema::Result::Node;

# Created by DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader
# DO NOT MODIFY THE FIRST PART OF THIS FILE

use strict;
use warnings;

use base 'DBIx::Class::Core';
__PACKAGE__->table("node");
__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
  "node_id",
  {
    data_type => "mediumint",
    extra => { unsigned => 1 },
    is_auto_increment => 1,
    is_nullable => 0,
  },
  "node_name",
  { data_type => "varchar", is_nullable => 0, size => 50 },
  "node_notes",
  { data_type => "varchar", is_nullable => 1, size => 1000 },
);
__PACKAGE__->set_primary_key("node_id");


# Created by DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader v0.07045 @ 2017-08-21 22:14:58
# DO NOT MODIFY THIS OR ANYTHING ABOVE! md5sum:bWXf98hpLJgNBU93aaRYkQ


# You can replace this text with custom code or comments, and it will be preserved on regeneration
1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real ans which came in DBIx list from Henry, is, whatever key you use, the col it corresponds to, should be in the query. all of above are ambiguous, they are not wrong, but they do not clarify the precise fact.

Answer (score 2):

https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::ResultSet#find:

> To aid with preparing the correct query for the storage you may supply the `key` attribute, which is the name of a [unique constraint](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::ResultSource#add_unique_constraint) (**the unique constraint corresponding to the [primary columns](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::ResultSource#primary_columns) is always named `primary`**).

(Emphasis mine.)

In other words, to use the primary key, you need to specify `{ key => 'primary' }`. Any other `key` attribute is looked up as the name of an additional unique constraint.

Comment: yes i had tried that. I get new error:  `$ ./test.pl
DBIx::Class::ResultSource::_minimal_valueset_satisfying_constraint(): Unable to satisfy requested constraint 'primary', missing values for column(s): 'node_id' at ./test.pl line 80`

Comment: `
sub addNode
{
 my $node = shift; my $lcNode = lc($node);
 my $id = $schema
  ->resultset('Node')
  ->find_or_create
  (
   { node_name => $lcNode },
   { key => 'primary' }
  );
 return $id;
}
`

Comment: @rajeev Yes, that's because your code makes no sense. If you want to find a row by its primary key (`node_id`), you need to specify the id value you're looking for.

Comment: thx. that fixed it. I think it use to work earlier (i am not very frequent user so i may be wrong). but now i am confused why is it returning a hash'? i think doc says it should return value of found record from Pri Index/Key.  When i print using Dumper i see the whole database (every table) is in that response/hash... `sub addNode
{
 my $node = shift; my $lcNode = lc($node);
 my $id = $schema
  ->resultset('Node')
  ->find_or_create
  (
   { node_name => $lcNode }
  );
 print Dumper($id);
 return $id;
}`

Comment: `find_or_create` returns a result object (representing the (found or newly added) row). Result objects are internally based on hashes and contain references to their DB schema, which is why you see pretty much everything if you blindly dump such an object.

Comment: thank you. sorry i am totally rusted, i hope to get my sheen back in few days (however little it was in first place :) ). I was able to get the object from hash, once i jogged my memory, your response certainly were valuable.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't make clear how `addNode` should work exactly. But if you want to lookup existing nodes by `node_name`, you should simply remove the `key` attribute:

```
my $id = $schema->resultset('Node')->find_or_create(
    { node_name => $lcNode }
);
```

But read the caveat in the [DBIC documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::ResultSet#find):

> If no such constraint is found, `find` currently defaults to a simple `search->(\%column_values)` which may or may not do what you expect. Note that this fallback behavior may be deprecated in further versions. If you need to search with arbitrary conditions - use "search". If the query resulting from this fallback produces more than one row, a warning to the effect is issued, though only the first row is constructed and returned as `$result_object`.

You should probably consider adding a unique constraint to `node_name`.

Comment: yeah, i am thinking to replace this with two staements, first a search ->count then if count < 1 then do the add....